# Problem with time update trigger, adding date when inserting

Tags: plsql, triggers

This is the table :

```
   CREATE TABLE Pracownik (
   IDPracownik int PRIMARY KEY,
   Imię varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   Nazwisko varchar(30) NOT NULL,
   Telefon varchar(30),
   Pensja FLOAT,
   DataDodania DATE,
   PoprzedniaPensja FLOAT,
   DataModyfikacji DATE
   );
```

Im creating this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DataDodania
BEFORE INSERT ON Pracownik

FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

SET NEW.DataDodania = now();

END;
```

But im getting an error :

```
 3/1       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
 3/5       PL/SQL: ORA-00922: brakująca lub niepoprawna opcja
```

How to solve it?

Comment: The pseudo-record is `:new`, not `new`. Also there's no `set`. What is `now()`? Did you want `sysdate`? But if so, why not set as the column default with `datadodania date default on null sysdate`?

Comment: Hi, thank you for fast reply. ':new' and getting rid of set solved the problem. Thank you

Comment: Now i have problem with this :

Comment: @WilliamRobertson anyway to pm you? I have more questions but cant ask here cause of limit of posts.

Answer (score 0):

@K0K0S, if you need to fill column  with the current date value, the trigger can be like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DataDodania
BEFORE INSERT 
  ON Pracownik
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  :new.DataDodania := sysdate;
END;
```